# Optimization in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve the optimization problem below, but it seems like I don't get something about how the function works. Anyone see what is wrong?

Would be happy to exchange for the newer LinearOptimization if I could get that to work.

```
numofoutput = {1, 2, 3};
lengthOutPut = {1, 3, 4};
usage = Table[0, 4];
waste = Table[0, 4];
outputInBeam = Table[0, 3, 4];

FindMinimum[

 {usage,


  0 <= usage <= 1 &&
    usage \[Element] Reals &&

   waste + Total[lengthOutPut  outputInBeam] == a usage &&

   Total[Transpose[outputInBeam]] == numofoutput &&

   waste \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0 &&

   outputInBeam \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0},

 {outputInBeam, waste, usage}]
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Your objective `usage` is a 4-vector of zeroes. Could you please write down the optimization problem in $\LaTeX$?